# Hiding plain text password in JVM startup argumnets. " ps -ef | grep 'javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword'"

Tags: jvm, passwords, startup, keystore, plaintext

The spring boot application's startup arguments having the trust and keystore details with plain text password.

Now I want to hide this plain text password details from process:

```
ps -ef | grep 'javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword'
```

I have created different properties file with below details. How we can add this properties file in startup arguments?

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStore
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType
javax.net.ssl.trustStore
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword
javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to preload properties file using a [Java Agent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html).

The agent code will be very simple.

**StartupProps.java**

```
import java.io.*;

public class StartupProps {

    public static void premain(String fileName) throws IOException {
        try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileName)) {
            System.getProperties().load(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

The agent also requires a manifest file:

**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Premain-Class: StartupProps
```

Now the agent needs to be compiled and packed into a .jar together with the manifest with the following command:

```
jar cvfm startupprops.jar MANIFEST.MF StartupProps.class
```

Now you can start your Java application with an agent, specifying the initial properties file:

```
java -javaagent:startupprops.jar=/path/to/initial.properties <args>
```

For your convenience, I've attached the prebuilt [startupprops.jar](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q_qQjGYbQY9Q0RDPfmwR8addXx8dT07Z/view?usp=sharing)