# Tomcat, hide javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword from -D options

Tags: ssl, tomcat

The application installed on Tomcat (9.0.36.B.RELEASE) connects to an external source using SSL (in this case, IBM MQ).  I therefore need to specify a truststore, and password for this truststore.

I got it to work adding this to the JVM_OPTS in `setenv.sh`:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/apps/certs/myapplication.truststore
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=TRUSTSTORE-PASSWORD
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/opt/apps/certs/myapplication.keystore
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=KEYSTORE-PASSWORD
```

Classic issue with this, the passwords are visible when I do `ps -ef|grep java` (runs on RHEL).

I have seen a couple suggestions on how to do this (like [Hiding plain text password in JVM startup argumnets. " ps -ef | grep 'javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59716492/hiding-plain-text-password-in-jvm-startup-argumnets-ps-ef-grep-javax-net)).  But these change/add code or configuration in the WAR file.

I am looking for a "tomcat" solution.  Is there a way to to this within the confines of Tomcat.  Changes to the WAR file are difficult to implement, as the application comes from a vendor.

**Note**: this is not for a connector configuration in web.xml since that would only setup SSL for incoming connections.  Here the application is making connections to an external system (so outbound from Tomcat's perspective).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add additional properties to `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties` and they will be sourced during Tomcat's startup. As you are certainly aware, system properties are global to the JVM, so there is no way to restrict this configuration to a single application only: the entire Tomcat server will be affected.

Almost all Java system properties can by set this way, with a few exceptions:

- `catalina.base` and `catalina.home` (obviously),
- the configuration for [Tomcat logging](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/logging.html),
- the configuration for JMX and other tools that start before user code.

**Attention**: You must check whether the `VersionLoggerListener` (defined in `server.xml`) does not have `logProps="true"`, otherwise the values of system properties will be logged. By default only the JVM arguments are logged.

Comment: Great, I will test this tomorrow!